# Fetch all item containing elements in list

Tags: jpa

I want to select all item with where his list exist in a param list. Can you help me? thanks in advance. Here is my code but doesn't work:

```
@Query("select * from Room r where exists(select * from Room r1 join r1.equipments e where e in :equipements)")
```

Comment: select * only works in SQL.  In JPQL, you need to explicietely list what you want returned.  In this case, try just "select r from room r.." and "select r1 from Room r1".  Get basic queries down before you try more complex subselect and exist queries.

Comment: indeed, it's a mistake. After some change, the select works :)

@Query("select r from Room r where exists(select r1 from Room r1 join r1.equipments e where e in :equipements)")